# Google Charts Gauge

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, charts, google-visualization

Most charting gauges seem to only support a starting value (min) of 0.

We have a need for the starting value to be the max and end value to be min so that the needle is maxed out for the lowest value.

[image]

E.g.
Think of the gauge as a ranking of top 20 developers the example below you were rated number 3.

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Rank', 20 - 3]
  ]);
  var options = {
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    redFrom: 0,
    redTo: 10,
    yellowFrom: 10,
    yellowTo: 15,
    greenFrom: 15,
    greenTo: 20,
    minorTicks: 20,
    max: 20,
    min: 0,
    majorTicks: ['20', '1']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['gauge']}]}"></script>

<div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

But the problem is since the gauge really does not support this I kinda hacked it to work they way I wanted.  Everything works great except for 1 thing. You will notice the value says 17 at the bottom because of this hack:

```
['Rank', 20-3]
```

Can I write a line of jquery to replace this value in the svg results?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change options and data:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Label', 'Value'],
['Rank', 3]
]);

var options = {
width: 250,
height: 250,
redFrom: 20,
redTo: 10,
yellowFrom: 10,
yellowTo: 5,
greenFrom: 5,
greenTo: 0,
minorTicks: 20,
max: 0,
min: 20,
majorTicks: ['20', '1']
  };

var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mblenton/xasppevj/

Comment: Wow I thought I tried reversing the min and max and it didnt work - I must have had some other bug.  Thanks for your answer!